# Multiple Entries in Database getting saved along with error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe in terminal

Tags: python, django

In my application I am trying to save a simple entry with the help of the following code.

```
        if form.is_valid():
            f=form.save(commit = False)
            f.Questionair=qset
            f.questionnumber = f.Questionair.questions_set.all().count()+1
            f.save()
            return redirect('/feedback/create/'+str(fbid))
```

What is happening is as soon as this code is executed using runserver I get the following error in the terminal.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 36076)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread self.finish_request(request, client_address)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__ super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__ self.finish()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish self.wfile.close()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close self.flush()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Along with this the entry is saved twice in the database. This does not happen everytime but 3 out of 4 time I am facing this issue. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and Django 1.6

Comment: could you use an auto incrementing field instead of doing it manually?

Comment: Auto Increment will not work as what questionnumber is not a primary key and repeats on based on the questionset. Also the same method works everywhere when the request takes time.